# Is there any way to refresh the DOM after a time without a click or any other event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there is any way to refresh the DOM, lets say with a function inside a timeout without need an event? like a click or something?

I basically need to go over all divs with a certain class, those divs are inserted by a javascript (I cant modify it) and I want to, after they are inserted, modify some content... is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's called the *meta refresh* tag.

Comment: If you are looking for a chain of action.. then try 'trigger' option. For example, you can execute an event by $('#controlid').trigger('<event>');

Comment: any idea how to do that in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
setInterval(function () {

    $('.certain-class').each(function () {
        $(this).html('modify some content');
    });

}, 2000); // every 2 seconds
```

If it should only run once after a delay, use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: but it wont work if the divs were added dinamically.. will it?

Comment: It should, unless you run `each` on a cached jquery result instead of a css selector

Comment: Ive tried something like that but nothing happened... I believe is because the divs were dinamically added...

Comment: have no idea how it works without refreshing the dom, but it does

Comment: It works because you are waiting for a couple of seconds and assuming (most times correctly) that by then the DOM will be updated with the dynamically added divs.  You are expecting the other script to be done in that time.  Iffy approach but OK.  I think it would be safer to listen for an event that signals the other script is done.  I bet there is one, if not endRequest (if the other script is not part of a postback), then something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.setInterval(function, delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to execute a `function` every *n* milliseconds.

Comment: thanks, I got that part, what I dont know is how to refresh the DOM without any event triggering

Answer (score 0):

I know you said without an event, but I think you mean without user interaction.  If that is the case, is this a place where you could use the endrequest event?  This event happens after an asynchronous postback is finished and control goes back to the browser, so if that other javascript is executed as part of an async postback, you could use this to tell the browser to run your code after that other one is all done.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)
```

where endRequestHandler is your code that is going to examine/change the DOM.